# Como desativar pastas compactadas no VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recentemente o VS Code está deixando as subpastas criadas em linhas (compatactadas). Como posso mostrá-las na visualização em árvore?

[image: Demonstração dos diretórios em linhas]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Conforme consta nas [notas da nova versão (1.41)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_compact-folders-in-explorer), de novembro de 2019, esse recurso pode ser controlado através da opção `explorer.compactFolders`.

Para desativar essas "pastas em linhas" ou "pastas compactadas", desmarque essa opção.

[image: Painel de configurações mostrando explorer.compactFolders no Visual Studio Code]

Comment: Opa!!! Agora deu certo, obrigado!!!